# Angularjs Form dirty not working for Dropdown

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a simple bootstrap form . For sake of example i have a input field and a dropdown.  I want to enable the save button only when the change is made. In order to do that, i made the save button enable only if the form is dirty.

The problem is  - When i change the input field it works, the button gets enabled, where as when i change the dropdown, which is basically selecting the list item, the form does not identify it as dirty and hence it is still disabled.

Any ideas? 
I also tried creating an hidden input field that gets updated everytime the select value gets updated  - but still it is noto working .

My sample form  (pls ignore any typos since i stripped of most of the code. The functionality works just fine. it is just the disabling of button that doesnt work)

```
<form name="customizeForm" id="customize-form" class="bm-form" data-ng-cloak novalidate data-ng-submit="ctrl.saveCustomization(customizeForm.$valid)">
    <!--if i change this input,  it works -->
    <input id="answer" type="text" name="answer" data-ng-model="ctrl.answer">

    <!--If i change the below dropdown, it doesnt work and the button is still disabled -->
    <div class="form-group dropdown col-xs-12 col-md-6" data-uib-dropdown data-keyboard-nav data-is-open="status[$index].isopen" data-ng-init="status[$index].newSelectedValue = ''">
        <button id="profile-menu" type="button" class="form-control select-control dropdown-togglebtn" data-uib-dropdown-toggle>
              <span class="selected" data-ng-bind-html="status[$index].newSelectedValue</span>
                 <span class="icon icon-down-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-aria-labelledby="menu">
            <li data-ng-repeat="answer in question.Answers">
                <a href="" data-ng-click="status[$parent.$index].newSelectedValue = answer.AnswerDesc; ctrl.selectDropdownOption(question.QuestionId, answer.AnswerId)">{{answer.AnswerDesc}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="save-profile" class="text-center form-submit">
        <button type="submit" data-ng-disabled="!customizeForm.$dirty" id="btn-profile-questionnaire" class="btn btn-card reverse" title="Save">
              Save</span>
              </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That's because no control is registered with `customizeForm` in the dropdown. A quick solution would be to call `customizeForm.$setDirty()` in the method `selectDropdownOption`.

Comment: @user2718281 how does it work for input fields?  in my real form , i have close to 15 input fields and it works for every single of them. i have 2 dropdowns, it doesnt work only for those two.

Comment: Your input fields work because they automatically registered. See [$addControl](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$addControl) docs. **Input elements using ngModelController do this automatically when they are linked.**. The dropdowns are not inputs